# iPhone Camera Recording FPS

Tags: iphone, camera

Is there a way to force iPhone to record at 30fps regardless of light conditions?

Is there a way to force iPhone camera to record at higher fps by reducing resolution?

What is the optimum way of finding out iPhone FPS other than analyzing recorded stream?

My main target is iPhone4 or 4S.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the frame record rate by using the min/max frame duration:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1388931-videominframeduration
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1390246-videomaxframeduration

You have to configure the capturing manually using the AVFoundation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW17

About the way of finding, I don't know but I do analyze the video stream.

You can see how its done from this code:

http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/face-tracking/

(just check the delegate method of the video capture, you will notice it immediately since it has FPS all over that part and it does say **// Update FPS calculation**)

**Edit:**

The previously linked documents are for mac os, in this case they are valid for the purpose but here are the iOS versions:

The AVFoundation class reference.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html

The Connection class reference (to set the fps).
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection

Comment: no, you are right, i made a mistake but for your purpose the documentation is the same. I linked the wrong pages. Ill update it.